# How to add a program to a list with right click button?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

When I right click on a file, a list of menu pops up. And, it has vim or emEditor for me to edit the file that I right clicked. I need to add emacs to that menu. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Add Your Own Program to the Windows Explorer Right Click Context Menu](http://scottiestech.info/2009/11/15/add-your-own-program-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-context-menu/).
There is also an older [GVim wiki note](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Right_click_in_Windows_Explorer_to_open_gvim_in_explorer_mode) describing this (it states the correct caveats on registry edits).

Answer (score 1):

One method is using the [registry](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/show/article02-026), another method is using an [application](http://thesoftpro.tripod.com/downloads/fe/) that edits the registry for you.