# How to run a batchfile automatically to setup environment whenever a command line shell is invoked?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, right-click

From [How to add a program to a list with right click button?](https://superuser.com/questions/191941/how-to-add-a-program-to-a-list-with-right-click-button), I could add "command" button to open command line prompt using right click.

I normally open the command line prompt to use Visual Studio tools, so running 'vcvarsall.bat' in the command line is the first thing that I normally do.

How can I automatize this? I mean, how can I run a batchfile automatically to setup environment whenever a command line shell is invoked?

Visual Studio provides a shortcut in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\Visual Studio Tools` named 'Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)' to do the setup environment for me. I thought about running this instead of command line, but the start in directory is fixed to the directory in VS2010, so I don't think that's a good idea.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a shortcut that will open a command prompt, run a batch file and then stay in the command prompt you can use `CMD`'s /K switch:

> /K - Carries out the command specified by string but remains

So create a shortcut (either on the desktop, or via the right-click setup mentioned in the answer to the other question you linked) and set the command/target to something like:

`cmd /K "c:\PathToBatch\vcvarsall.bat"`

Answer (score 2):

Based on techie007's answer, I could use regedt32 to change the registry to run the batchfile with /K option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings.

Choose the Advanced tab and then click Environment Variables.

Edit and /or add User variables.

Now, whenever you open a shell, these varaibles will be set.